# R - How to delete rows before a certain phrase and after a certain phrase in a single column

Tags: r, rows, data-cleaning

Hi I would like to delete rows before a certain phrase and then after the same (almost) phrase which appears later on. I guess another way to look at it would be keep only the data from the start and end of a certain section.

My data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(time = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)), 
                 type = c("","","GMT:yyyy-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS_LT:2016-10-18_06:09:53","(K)","","","","(K)","(K)","","(K)","GMT:yyyy-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS_CAM:2016-10-18_06:20:03",""),
                 names = c("J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J","J"))
```

and I would like to delete everything before the first `GMT:yyyy...` phrase and after the second `GMT:yyyy...` phrase. So the end product would be

```
time   type                                                    names
3      GMT:yyyy-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS_LT:2016-10-18_06:09:53           J
4      (K)                                                      J
5                                                               J
6                                                               J
7                                                               J 
8      (K)                                                      J
9      (K)                                                      J
10                                                              J
11     (K)                                                      J
12     GMT:yyyy-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS_LT:2016-10-18_06:20:03           J
```

I thought `subset` might work but it is giving me problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using grep, you can locate the indexes of the rows where your pattern is found:

```
ind=grep("^GMT",df$type)
```

Then you can keep only the rows between the two indexes:

```
df=df[ind[1]:ind[2],]
```

Comment: You don't really need the `as.character` (`grep` works with factors) or `value = FALSE` (that's the default) or even the `^` (for this example, anyway), but this is a good answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer to remove the `as.character` and `value=F`. I've left the ^ just for extra safety.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df2 <- df %>% slice(str_which(type, "GMT")[1]:str_which(type, "GMT")[2])
```

Comment: You could use `which.min` and `which.max` to simplify a bit, or better, just use `str_which`, which is the equivalent of `grep` with `value = FALSE`.